# Placing a List of Schemes in the Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, chemmacros

I am using the [`chemmacros`](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros?lang=en) package -- specifically its `scheme` module -- to generate a **List of Schemes**. (Note: the [`chemmacros`](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros?lang=en) package has been recently updated so that it is compatible with the [`book`](https://ctan.org/pkg/book?lang=en) class.)

I am also using the [`tocloft`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft?lang=en) package to change the number widths of the List of Figures and List of Tables.

In the following MWE, why does the **List of Schemes** appear as a subentry of **List of Tables** in the Table of Contents? How can I get the **List of Schemes** to appear as a separate entry in the **Table of Contents**?

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
]{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{
  barriers/use, barriers/reset,
  use-id-as-short,
}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\setchemformula{charge-hshift=.5pt}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usechemmodule{scheme}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{2.9em}
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{2.9em}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\listoftables

\addcontentsline{toc}{scheme}{\listschemename}
\listofschemes

\chapter{First chapter}
Refer to \cref{fig:firstfig} using cleveref package.
Refer to \cref{tbl:firsttbl}.
Refer to scheme, \cref{scm:firstscheme}.
% Example figure
\begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.02\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{Caption of figure in first chapter.}\label{fig:firstfig}
\end{figure}

% Example table 
\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \toprule
    A & B\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Caption of table in first chapter.}\label{tbl:firsttbl}
\end{table}

\begin{scheme}[!h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.02\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Caption of first scheme.}\label{scm:firstscheme}
\end{scheme}

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: You could try using addcontentsline{toc}{chapter} instead of addcontentsline{toc}{scheme}

Comment: @leandriis Thank you. I'm sorry; I guess I need some more sleep.